# Uploading file Link in PHP

Tags: php

Sir, I want image uploading system for my users.
I want that image must be uploaded in IMAGE folder and also its location link suppose to be copied in my Mysql database table.
The problem is that image is uploaded in IMAGE folder in dir but in php MYSQL table its link does't get uploaded or copied.

Following are the scripts, Kindly Help to solve this:

**Form Page:**

```
<form action="UplaodGallery_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
                <table width="414" height="78" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="111" height="15">Upload Photo :</td>
                    <td width="297"><label for="file"></label>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Description :</td>
                    <td><label for="desc"></label>
                      <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><p>
                      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
                    </p></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
```

**UplaodGallery_script.php Page Code**

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conne.php'); ?>
<?php

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }


    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


      }
    }

else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }


$path="upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$desc=$_POST["desc"];

mysql_select_db("$database_conne"); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo ('desc', 'photopath') VALUES ('$desc','$path')");

mysql_close ($conne);
?>
```

Comment: Basic debugging first. What *gets* copied into the database? What does a new row look like?

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: adding an id field will make it easier do delete photos later on, plus using mysql_real_escape_string($desc) is a must!

Answer (score 0):

Heyup,

It looks to me like the problem is in the `mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo ('desc', 'photopath') VALUES ('$desc','$path')");` code.

May you try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (`desc`, `photopath`) VALUES ('$desc','$path')");
```

and see what happens? I put in backticks around the column names, that should solve the problem